# Painted PSU and Case - How do I connect my Anti Static Strap?

Tags: case

I'm purchasing an anti static strap due to my house being all carpet. My case ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07H4V9T9R/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H4V9T9R)) and my PSU (https://pcpartpicker.com/product/8P7CmG/evga-bq-500w-80-bronze-certified-semi-modular-atx-power-supply-110-bq-0500-k1) both appear to be painted. Any thoughts on how I can connect my anti static strap?

Comment: It doesn't have to be connected to the case, just to something grounded. Unless your case isn't at ground potential, anyway.

Comment: Okay, do you gave an example of what would be grounded? I was also told I could connect it into the wall outlet. If I can do that, how would I?

Comment: For readers interested in this topic, the same question was asked a few hours ago on [linus tech tips](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/1104175-all-painted-metal-on-my-case-how-do-i-connect-an-esd-strap/), [tom's hardware](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/no-painted-metal-on-psu-or-case.3524409/) and [pc part picker](https://pcpartpicker.com/forums/topic/328647-all-painted-metal-on-my-case-and-psu-how-do-i-connect-an-esd-strap), so other replies may be found there.

Comment: That was me. I could get no answer on 2 of them.

Comment: If there truly isn't any bare metal when you examine the case carefully then your only course is to create some. Pick an unobtrusive spot on the case, say in the bottom or the back, drill a small hole, scrape off the paint around the hole on the inside and insert a nut and bolt. Tighten them  and clip your strap to the bare metal bolt. You could always remove the nut and bolt once the system is up and running.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But I might not have a need for that. I have asked a question on amazon about if the psu is metal, and the 2 people that answered said yes. I have also emailed EVGA to comfirm, so yeah. Once I comfirm, I'm supposed to put the alligator clip on the psu grilles on the back, right?

Answer (score 1):

The concept is to equalize the static potential of the user-connected to strap and the case chassis on any metal-conductive surface or screw connection or 0V connection such as the USB port or VGA port.

> It does not demand earth ground connection, but this permits the ground strap to use any earth ground connection. But often PC service is done with Cordset disconnected.

The same protection by trough the case 1st before sensitive electronics with frequent or constant contact.

Comment: Bold type would be better than all caps.

Comment: Done... @Moab. TY, my concentration is wanting... post op Thoracic to elbow bypass

Comment: I understand, good luck with recovery.